# KnockoutJS, passing field of object in the array as <input> value

Tags: knockout.js

Is there a possibility to pass a field of object in an observable array as a value of input?
For example, i need something similar like this:

```
 <input type="text" data-bind="value: persons()[0].name"/>
```

So i could edit a field of object in the array.

Comment: Have you tried it? Because it should work. If it's not working, show us your view model, or better yet, post a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/)

Comment: Yes i've tryed it now and found what i've did wrong. Sorry for this useless question, but sometimes you just need to ask somebody a question, to instantly figure out what you did wrong. I've found mistake while did a fiddle model :)

Comment: Happens to all of us. Sometimes just working through the problem by turning into a question is all you need.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It works (just tested it out of curiosity on one of my projects)

However, your "persons" array is a knockout observable array. There is a chance that the binding operation fails because the "persons" array is null or not populated with at least one object when you start your web application.

If you really want to do that, I suggest you first check in your binding that the persons array is populated, example:

```
<input type="text" data-bind="value: persons().length ? persons()[0].name : null"/>
```

You ensure that the binding operation will not crash, regardless of the initialization state of the array.

Comment: Thanks for "check" tip. I'll try to use it in future

Answer (score 0):

Look into using the foreach binding in knockout, in this example below I used the comment bindings along with the foreach binding.

```
 <tbody>
                             <!-- ko foreach: Movies-->
                             <tr>
                              <td data-bind="text: Title"></td>
                              <td data-bind="text: Description"></td>
                              <td data-bind="text: Rating"></td>
                             </tr>
                              <!-- /ko -->
                            </tbody>
                        </table>
```